# SQL: Adding a column with data to an existing SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (tableA):

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| def | 456 |
| ghi | 789 |

to which I want to add `Col3` with entries `S`, `M`, `L` such that (tableB)

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | S |
| abc | 123 | M |
| abc | 123 | L |
| def | 456 | S |
| def | 456 | M |
| def | 456 | L |
| ghi | 789 | S |
| ghi | 789 | M |
| ghi | 789 | L |

I only know of a way to add a column with single values (i.e. by using the `ALTER` command with `default`) but not with a column multiple data points.

Comment: You may add a column with no data and then insert all the source records joined with list of values for new column

Comment: Probably easiest to insert rows into a new table to replace the original using a cross join to your col3 data.

Comment: The table is very large, it has a lot of entries in `col1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the column

```
ALTER TABLE tablea
            ADD COLUMN col3 varchar(1);
```

and set the value for the existing rows to `'S'`.

```
UPDATE tablea
       SET col3 = 'S';
```

Then use an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` from the table cross joined with `'M'`s and `'L'`s into the the table to insert the missing rows.

```
INSERT INTO table3
            (col1,
             col2,
             col3)
            SELECT t.col1,
                   t.col2,
                   v.col3
                   FROM tablea t
                        CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('M'),
                                           ('L')) v
                                                  (col3);
```

Comment: Thank you this works. This would also work:
```select a.* ,c.col3 from tableA a cross join (values ('M'),('L'),('S')) c (col3)
```

Comment: @labrynth: "This would also work: ..." -- It would generate such a set, yes. But it wouldn't materialize it in the table as you have asked for.